# Bootstrap 3 Equal Height Rows Not Working 100% On Our Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

We have almost completed the development of our Bootstrap 3 based web site, but where we need to display columns comprising of thumbnails and text they don't always wrap and align correctly. It works on Chrome and Safari, but doesn't work 100% of the time on Firefox, and we have pretty much run out of ideas.

We are using a script from CSS Tricks (http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/) to set the rows to equal height.

The best way to describe what is happening is to let you take a look for yourself.  A good example is on [this page](http://www.drapertools.com/b2crtest/catprods.pgm?name=Spirit%20Levels&cat=00007875)

Set the view to settings to Show All Products and the Display to Gallery View.

On page load, the script ("columnConform") should set the height of columns with id "page-wrap" to equal the height of the tallest in each row. It doesn't always do this 100%.

If you resize the window, the script will again be triggered, and generally works better this time, although not 100% in Firefox.

The script code for setting equal heights is below (on our site in file thumbnail-row-fix.js):

```js
// these are (ruh-roh) globals. You could wrap in an
    // immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) if you wanted to...
    var currentTallest = 0,
        currentRowStart = 0,
        rowDivs = new Array();

    function setConformingHeight(el, newHeight) {
        // set the height to something new, but remember the original height in case things change
        el.data("originalHeight", (el.data("originalHeight") == undefined) ? (el.height()) : (el.data("originalHeight")));
        el.height(newHeight);
    }

    function getOriginalHeight(el) {
        // if the height has changed, send the originalHeight
        return (el.data("originalHeight") == undefined) ? (el.height()) : (el.data("originalHeight"));
    }

    function columnConform() {

        // find the tallest DIV in the row, and set the heights of all of the DIVs to match it.
        $('#page-wrap > div').each(function() {

            // "caching"
            var $el = $(this);

            var topPosition = $el.position().top;

            if (currentRowStart != topPosition) {

                // we just came to a new row.  Set all the heights on the completed row
                for(currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) setConformingHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest);

                // set the variables for the new row
                rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
                currentRowStart = topPosition;
                currentTallest = getOriginalHeight($el);
                rowDivs.push($el);

            } else {

                // another div on the current row.  Add it to the list and check if it's taller
                rowDivs.push($el);
                currentTallest = (currentTallest < getOriginalHeight($el)) ? (getOriginalHeight($el)) : (currentTallest);

            }
            // do the last row
            for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) setConformingHeight(rowDivs[currentDiv], currentTallest);

        });

    }       

    $(window).resize(function() {
        columnConform();
    });

    // Dom Ready
    // You might also want to wait until window.onload if images are the things that
    // are unequalizing the blocks
    window.onload = function() {
        columnConform();
        //$(window).load(function() {
        //columnConform();
//  setTimeout(function(){columnConform()},6000);
    };
```

Supposedly window.onload or $(window).load are the same and are triggered when the DOM and ALL images have loaded. If so, I can't explain why the script works differently when the page is loaded to when the window is resized in Firefox.

Maybe it's a bug in the latest version of Firefox, but I can't see anything relevant on the forums.

Any thoughts, tips and ways to try and get this working would be much appreciated.
I hope I explained this adequately, displaying the page ought to trigger the problem.

Comment: A way to do this is use display:table-cell into a bootstrap row. It's kind of dirty but it's working generally fine.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. [Pseudo-Elements](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-solving-the-equal-height-column-conundrum--cms-20403) and [Table-Cell](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height). JS/jQuery can get buggy and unreliable. If you have IE 9+ support only then you can use [Flexbox](http://acmetech.github.io/todc-bootstrap-3/examples/equal-height-columns/).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Can't get this working since both Table-Cell and Pseudo-Elements seem to want to work with columns on a single row.
Our columns are defined as a single row and need to float onto multiple lines, 3 or 4 (or 1) per line depending on the window size.

Comment: Just updated to Firefox 31.0 and that didn't seem to make a difference unfortunately. The rows align correctly until you get most of the way down the page, and then there is a whole row of blanks where it's not wrapping correctly.  You are limited in what you can do because the columns have to remain responsive.  Short of writing a script that checks the window size, determines the columns per row, and inserts the "clearfix" class where needed, I can't think how to proceed further. So close and yet so far away...

Answer (score 0):

I have (for now) had to give up on finding the ideal solution to this problem, but have managed to find a solution that at least works.

The "columnConform" script works by setting the height of all columns in a row (ie: having the same offset from the top of the page) to the height of the tallest column in the row.

Unfortunately where columns are of sufficient unequal height, they do not output to the page in the correct row, and therefore this script will not fix the problem.

A minor change makes the script think that ALL columns have an offset of 0 from the top of the page, therefore they are ALL in the same row and are all given the height of the tallest.

Provided that there isn't a single column that is a LOT taller than the rest, this is not a problem. On most of our pages fortunately doing this only results in a little more white space between the rows than we wanted to achieve.

The code change is as follows:

```
   // var topPosition = $el.position().top;
      var topPosition = 0;
```